# What does `pgrep -P` without PID do?

Tags: linux

I need to know if a process has any children process, so I use the command

```
pgrep -P <ProcessID>
```

Then I get all the children processes. But when I use the command with an empty value and double quotation marks like that:

```
pgrep -P ""
```

As a response I get the numbers: `1`, `2` What is the meaning of that result?

Comment: Note not all implementations/versions work this way. In my Debian 8 `pgrep -P ""` behaves like you described, yet in Kubuntu 16.04.3 it writes syntax help to `stderr` and returns exit status 2.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's giving you the result for `pgrep -P "0"`, which is the swapper process, the first process. You can verify with `ps -eaf`, first two lines should show `0` as PPID (parent process ID).